# browser not animating large divs

Tags: html

I have a page(imaginary page resembling to original)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img").attr("width","180");
$("div").click(function(){$(this).slideToggle();
});});
</script><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"></div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is not animating and seems like as it is hung in the browser it is animating for small no. of images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/JSpu5/ or http://jsfiddle.net/JSpu5/1/

```
$("div").click(function(){$(this).slideToggle();});
```

If you click on the div it animates the slide, but then you can't see the div anymore.  Think of a better logic to do the animation, maybe with a button.

Make sure you include JQuery js files correctly.  Try it this way

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" />
```

**Edit:**

Here with an image http://jsfiddle.net/JSpu5/2/

Comment: I dont have the images I cant display them, but Ill update it with random images